# ICC profil in PDF using Graphicsmagick

Tags: imagemagick, graphicsmagick

We use a Graphicsmagick to convert JPG/PNG to pdf.

We need to get the ICC Profil that the JPG/PNG contains because the PDF is printed.

How can we do that ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: what do you try so far?

Answer (score 1):

You can see what profiles are embedded in an image with ImageMagick's `identify` command like this:

```
identify -format "%[profiles]" image.tif
8bim,icc,xmp
```

i.e. this image has IPTC, ICC and XMP profiles embedded.

Then you can extract them like this:

```
convert image.tif icc:profile.icc        # extract ICC profile

convert image.tif 8bim:profile.8bim      # extract 8bim profile

convert image.tif icm:profile.icm        # extract ICM profile
```